How to use parallel propagator explain path dependence derived from a metric field?
In Sean Caroll's Spacetime and geometry. He gives a method to write down a solution to the parallel transport equations.
If a vector $V(x)$ being transported down a path $l$, The  vector field is described with equation:
$$\partial_\mu V(x)=\Gamma_\mu V(x)$$
The solution of the equation can be described with parallel propagator(in mathematics it is also called product integration):
\begin{equation}
V(x)=P(x, x_0)V(x_0) = \mathcal{P} \exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x  \Gamma_\mu(x){\rm dx^\mu }\right)V(x_0)
\end{equation}
If there exists a matrix function $A(x)$ which satisfies the equation:
$$\partial_\mu A(x)=\Gamma_\mu A(x)$$
Then $\Gamma_\mu$ can be written as $\partial_\mu A(x) A^{-1}(x)$. and the parallel propagator constructed with such a connection is:
$$P(x, x_0) = \mathcal{P} \exp\left(\int_{x_0}^x  \partial_\mu A(x)A^{-1}(x){\rm dx^\mu }\right)
=A(x)A^{-1}(x_0)$$
So the parallel propagator is path independent, the curvature of $\Gamma_\mu$ is zero.
$$R_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu \Gamma_\nu-\partial_\nu \Gamma_\mu+[\Gamma_\mu \  \Gamma_\nu]=0$$
In this way we can relate a matrix function(the change of the matrix between two points is path independent) and a zero curvature connection.
If we use parallel propagator to analyse metric compatable equation:
$$∇_ρ g_{μν}=g_{μν,ρ}  -Γ_{ρμ}^λ g_{λν}-Γ_{ρν}^λ g_{μλ}=0$$
If the metric $g_{μν}$ moves along a path $l$ between points $x_0$ and $x$, then the solution can be described with parlallel propagator:
$$g(x)=P(x,x_0)g(x_0)P^T(x,x_0)$$
If $Γ_\mu(x)$ the connection compatible with metric $g(x)$ whose curvature is not zero.then parlallel propagator $P(x,x_0)$ is path dependent. but because $g(x)$ is a field, So $P(x,x_0)g(x_0)P^T(x,x_0)$ must be path independent. The only possible parlallel propagator should take such a form:
$$P(x,x_0)=A(x)P'(x,x_0)=A(x)\mathcal{P}\exp\int^x_{x_0}\Gamma'_\mu(x)dx^\mu$$
Here $A(x)$ is a matrix function. We demand the curvature of $\Gamma'_\mu(x)$ is not zero. $R(\Gamma'_\mu)\neq 0$ and:
$$P'(x,x_0)g(x_0)P'^T(x,x_0)=g(x_0)$$
Then the metric is only determined by the matrix function $A(x)$, and has nothing to do with the path dependent part $P'(x,x_0)$. So

For any metric field, there exist connections with zero curvature compatible with the metric. is it true?

Although there exist connections compatible with a metric field whose curvature is not zero. but in the definition of the metric field, the path dependent part was canceled. so we can get a metric field (path independent). Then how can we get a non-zero curvature connection purely from a metric field?

If we get a Christoffel connection from a metric field,  when a vector moves along a closed path and return to the original point then the change of the vector should be a rotation? It seemed that the rotation is derived from a metric field? but metric is rotation invariant. So a metric field can not offer any information about rotation. I am confused about this problem, Can anyone offer some examples to explain this problem?


